# What Is The Number of Active S-boxes over 5 Rounds of Fides AE cipher?

Tags: block-cipher, s-boxes, mds

It is mention in the paper ["
Fides: Lightweight Authenticated Cipher with Side-Channel Resistance for Constrained Hardware"](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/424.pdf) , the number of active S-boxes of Fides cipher is 22 over 5 rounds but my result shows it is 25((9-3-1-3-9))using the same concept used in midori (same almost MDS matrix) to construct MILP model.

Q. Is anyone else got same results as mine? if not , is there any steps should i take to find the correct answer other than exhaustive search?

Comment: How did you get the result?

Comment: as mentioned in the question, I extended in the MILP model used in Midori to include 8 columns Not 4 and changed the shift rows values.

Comment: Just curious, can you share the MILP code?

Comment: very large number of equations to post it here

Comment: Post it on Github and link here (may be) :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your result is accurate: 25 active S-boxes is the best you can do in a 5-round trail. Here's an example for the 5-bit S-box variant, respecting the S-box constraints (and assuming I read the specification correctly):
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathtt{19} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{1c} & \mathtt{1b} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} \\ 
\mathtt{00} & \mathtt{1c} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{1e} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} \\ 
\mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{0c} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{1b} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} \\ 
\mathtt{00} & \mathtt{1b} & \mathtt{04} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} \\ 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
\xrightarrow{SB}
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathtt{11} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{04} & \mathtt{10} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} \\
\mathtt{00} & \mathtt{11} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{10} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} \\
\mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{11} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{04} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} \\
\mathtt{00} & \mathtt{04} & \mathtt{10} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} \\
\end{bmatrix}
\xrightarrow{SR}
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathtt{11} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{04} & \mathtt{10} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} \\
\mathtt{11} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{10} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} \\
\mathtt{11} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{04} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} \\
\mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{04} & \mathtt{10} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} \\
\end{bmatrix}
\xrightarrow{MC}
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} \\
\mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{04} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} \\
\mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{10} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} \\
\mathtt{11} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
\xrightarrow{SB}
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} \\
\mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{0f} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} \\
\mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{0f} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} \\
\mathtt{0f} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} \\
\end{bmatrix}
\xrightarrow{SR}
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} \\
\mathtt{00} & \mathtt{0f} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} \\
\mathtt{00} & \mathtt{0f} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} \\
\mathtt{00} & \mathtt{0f} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} \\
\end{bmatrix}
\xrightarrow{MC}
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathtt{00} & \mathtt{0f} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} \\
\mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} \\
\mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} \\
\mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
\xrightarrow{SB}
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathtt{00} & \mathtt{11} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} \\
\mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} \\
\mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} \\
\mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} \\
\end{bmatrix}
\xrightarrow{SR}
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathtt{00} & \mathtt{11} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} \\
\mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} \\
\mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} \\
\mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} \\
\end{bmatrix}
\xrightarrow{MC}
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} \\
\mathtt{00} & \mathtt{11} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} \\
\mathtt{00} & \mathtt{11} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} \\
\mathtt{00} & \mathtt{11} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
\xrightarrow{SB}
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} \\
\mathtt{00} & \mathtt{02} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} \\
\mathtt{00} & \mathtt{08} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} \\
\mathtt{00} & \mathtt{04} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} \\
\end{bmatrix}
\xrightarrow{SR}
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} \\
\mathtt{02} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} \\
\mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{08} \\
\mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{04} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} \\
\end{bmatrix}
\xrightarrow{MC}
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathtt{02} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{04} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{08} \\
\mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{04} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{08} \\
\mathtt{02} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{04} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} \\
\mathtt{02} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{08} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
\xrightarrow{SB}
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathtt{06} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{0b} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{1d} \\
\mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{0c} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{1b} \\
\mathtt{01} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{02} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} \\
\mathtt{03} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{03} \\
\end{bmatrix}
\xrightarrow{SR}
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathtt{06} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{0b} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{1d} \\
\mathtt{00} & \mathtt{0c} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{1b} & \mathtt{00} \\
\mathtt{02} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{01} & \mathtt{00} \\
\mathtt{03} & \mathtt{03} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} \\
\end{bmatrix}
\xrightarrow{MC}
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathtt{01} & \mathtt{0f} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{1a} & \mathtt{00} \\
\mathtt{07} & \mathtt{03} & \mathtt{0b} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{01} & \mathtt{1d} \\
\mathtt{05} & \mathtt{0f} & \mathtt{0b} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{1b} & \mathtt{1d} \\
\mathtt{04} & \mathtt{0c} & \mathtt{0b} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{00} & \mathtt{1a} & \mathtt{1d} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

So where does the 22 come from? Well, modeling the S-box and the linear layer exactly can be costly. Instead, we can represent each nibble by a single bit and use the branch number $4$ of the almost-MDS layer to obtain a lower bound of active S-boxes. That is, for each column of the state in MixColumns, we have
$$
\begin{align*}
\sum (x_i + y_i) &\ge 4d \\
d &\ge x_i \\
d &\ge y_i \,,
\end{align*}
$$
for dummy variable $d$, input and output variables $x_i$ and $y_i$.
Because this is an almost-MDS matrix, we also need to additionally ensure that the output is nonzero if the input is (as described [here](https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/547)):
$$
\begin{align*}
4\sum y_i - \sum x_i &\ge 0 \\
4\sum x_i - \sum y_i &\ge 0 \,.
\end{align*}
$$

However, when one does this, it results in the looser bound of $\ge 18$ active S-boxes over 5 rounds, not 22! So it remains a mystery where the 22 came from. The same observations also apply to 6 rounds, and possibly above.